# Pipe and watch piped output?

Tags: bash, shell, redirection

I want to make a shell-pipe like this:

```
producer | analyser > report.txt
```

and watch the output of `producer` while it is generating data (a big log-file) for analysis.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `/bin/sh` and compatibles:

```
producer | tee /dev/fd/3 | (analyser > report.txt) 3>&1
```

I've tested this only on Linux and Cygwin.
On some Unix-likes you may have to change `/dev/fd/3` to whatever their equivalent is.

Comment: that will show and save the output of analyser, right? I want to see the output of producer.

Comment: sorry - better now?

Comment: That will save producer's output to report.txt and I'd have to watch it using "tail -F". Not exactly what I wanted...

Comment: Fixed once again.  I should learn to actually read stuff before replying.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I had to use /dev/fd/2 for stdout. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to understand `/dev/fd/3`, I believe to have learned that `3` isn't defined, and therefore doesn't work everywhere, while `/dev/fd/2` sends the output to stderr, which isn't sent into the pipe by default.

Comment: Indeed, numbers 3 and up don't exist by default. Try running `sh -c 'echo hello 1>&3 && ls -l /dev/fd/' 3>&1` and you will see `/dev/fd/3`.