# How to print and pipe log file at the same time?

Tags: bash, grep, tee

I use this to check the log lines of a log file until the occurrence of a specific event (taken from [this answer to *Monitoring a file until a string is found*](https://superuser.com/a/900134/510395)):

```
(tail -f -n 0 test.log &) | grep -q 'SPEFICIC LOG MESSAGE'
```

This works, but I also want the log lines to be printed to stdout while waiting for the event. I am looking for something like `tee`, but I want to print and pipe at the same time.

I tried [this answer to *Pipe and watch piped output?*](https://superuser.com/a/388327/510395), leading to:

```
(tail -f -n 0 test.log &) | tee /dev/fd/2 | grep -q 'SPEFICIC LOG MESSAGE'
```

but then the command never quits, presumably because `grep` fails to interrupt `tail` when it finds a match, so `tail` continues to deliver data to `tee`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `grep` exits, your `tee` will exit due to SIGPIPE only when it tries to write more to the pipe. This is how pipes work. This means you need one more line from `tail`. `tee` will exit *eventually*, unless `tail` is forever silent after printing `SPEFICIC LOG MESSAGE`.

`tail … | grep …` is similar in general. The trick with `(tail … &)` makes your main shell not wait for `tail` (it waits for the subshell instead, and the subshell does not wait for `tail` thanks to `&`).

You can use the same trick with `tee`:

```
(tail -f -n 0 test.log &) | (tee /dev/fd/2 &) | grep -q 'SPEFICIC LOG MESSAGE'
```

The main shell will wait for the two subshells and `grep`. The subshells will exit almost immediately, so it's `grep` what matters. When `grep` exits, the main shell will continue.

`tee` will stay in the background until it tries to write more. Only then it gets SIGPIPE and exits. This requires one extra line from the log.

In turn `tail` will stay in the background until it tries to write more after `tee` exits. This requires another extra line from the log. [Unless your `tail` is smart](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690). GNU `tail` detects broken pipe immediately, it does not require the trick. Using the trick with GNU `tail` is harmless, so when in doubt, use it.

`tee` is not that smart, it does require the trick.

The command I gave you should work, but keep in mind `tee` and `tail` will stay in the background until the next line appears in the log. If your tail is not smart then it will stay for yet another line.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you! I had just copied the line form the other answer, which unfortunately does not explain what `( ... &)` actually does (and I had no idea).

Comment: wouldn't `(tail -f -n 0 test.log | tee /dev/fd/2 &) | grep -q 'SPEFICIC LOG MESSAGE'` work as well ?

Comment: @Uriel I think it would.