# How to move files containing NULL to a separate folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have over 10000 files in a folder. I was using an Rscript to preprocess the files. It displayed an error:

> Error in read.table(wd, comment.char ="#", header=T, sep='\t'):
> empty beginning of file

When I opened the file in a text editor the file was empty but the size of the file was around 4 MB. Next, I opened the file in a Notepad++, I was able to see the content as `NULL NULL NULL ... NULL`

[image: File example]

I want to move these kind of files from the folder to another folder. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: (1) "these kind of files" – What kind exactly? Files containing null bytes only? Files containing at least N (how many?) null bytes at the beginning? Files beginning with a null byte? Files containing at least one null byte? (2) What is the OS? (3) By "from the folder", do you mean "from the folder and subfolders"?

Comment: (1+) Or strictly files resulting in the `empty beginning of file` error from `read.table(wd, comment.char ="#", header=T, sep='\t')`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I want to move all non-text files

Comment: [In terms of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403)? I mean: should we pay attention to `{LINE_MAX}`? and incomplete lines? Or to null characters only? What is the OS?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu. The files whichever is not `ASCII` need to move to separate directory.

Comment: The null character belongs to the ASCII set… OK, I think I get it anyway.

Comment: Please clarify what "keep" means. Just move them once or keep moving them? Please edit your post accordingly, I changed it to "move" for now. Also, did you attempt anything? Keep in mind that this is not a free scripting service and you'll much more likely receive help if you include some script that you tried to write/use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Testing a single file

`grep` in the following command will return exit status 0 if `some_file` contains at least one null character:

```
<some_file tr -dc '\0' | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -q ''
```

Unless the shell option `pipefail` is set, the exit status of `grep` will become the exit status of the whole pipeline, if `tr`s exit. `pipefail` is unset by default and you want it this way (see [what may happen otherwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743266/108618)).

I wrote "if `tr`s exit" because after `grep` exits the second `tr` needs to write something in order to get SIGPIPE; then the first `tr` needs to write something in order to get SIGPIPE; only then the pipe is considered terminated. It may happen the first `tr` keeps and keeps reading even if `grep` exits early and the outcome is known. If `some_file` is a special file generating a neverending stream of bytes (similar to e.g. `/dev/urandom`) and there is not enough null bytes in the stream then the pipe will never exit. For a regular file the worst case scenario is when the first `tr` exits after reading the whole file. If `some_file` is a regular file then `tr`s will exit *eventually* for sure.

[This answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1757155/432690) explains a trick you can use to speed things up. In your case the trick will leave `tr`(s) in the background. Since you're going to test many files, piling up `tr`s is not a good idea.

In practice it's often enough to test the very beginning of a file. The following command will read up to 2 KiB of `some_file` and analyze only this part:

```
head -c 2048 some_file | tr -dc '\0' | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -q ''
```

Alternatively you can use the command `file`, for a big file it won't read the whole file either. Here we generate exit status 0 if `file --mime-type` does not print `text/whatever`:

```
! file --brief --mime-type some_file | grep -q 'text/'
```

I expect the two commands to agree in vast majority of cases; there may be cases (files) where they differ though.

---

#### Testing many files (and moving accordingly)

This snippet will loop over files in the current working directory, test regular files and move them accordingly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
(
shopt -s nullglob
for f in ./*; do
   [ -f "$f" ] \
   && ! [ -L "$f" ] \
   && head -c 2048 "$f" | tr -dc '\0' | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -q '' \
   && mv -v "$f" /target/directory/
done
)
```

Notes:

- Create `/target/directory/` beforehand.
- You can use the other test. The relevant line will be:

  ```
     && ! file --brief --mime-type "$f" | grep -q 'text/' \
  ```
- The subshell `(…)` is in case you want to paste the code into an interactive shell. Thanks to the subshell, the code won't change anything in your current shell.
- Normally `*` does not match hidden files. Append `dotglob` to the `shopt -s` line to make `*` match hidden files.
- If you want recursiveness, append `globstar` to the `shopt -s` line and use `./**` instead of `./*`. Be careful, if there are files with identical names then you may lose data; consider `mv -i`.
- We want to conditionally move regular files. `[ -f "$f" ]` checks if we're dealing with a regular file; but it also succeeds for a symlink to (a symlink to (a symlink to (…))) a regular file. This is the reason we additionally check if the file is not a symlink (`! [ -L "$f" ]`). If you want the code to treat symlinks to regular files like regular files then delete the whole line containing `[ -L` (including the terminating newline character).
- In general commands and code in this answer are not portable. You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and said the OS is Ubuntu, I made use of what Bash and Ubuntu provide.
- A solution with `find` is possible. Each of our tests is a pipeline, so `find` would have to spawn shell(s) anyway.